# Get monitor serial number using PyQt

Tags: linux, windows, qt, pyqt, multiple-monitors

I helping out on an FOSS application which uses PyQt 5. It is a dual screen application, and I would like to track the monitors that get connected, and persist settings if they get disconnected.

We're using [QScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html) for the info we need, and this is great, but on Windows and on Linux the 'serialNumber' property returns an empty string, as does the 'manufacturer' and 'model' properties.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui
app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

print(repr(app.screens()[0].serialNumber()))
```

Any suggestions on how I can obtain the serial number?

For Windows the snippet at https://www.activexperts.com/admin/scripts/wmiscripts/python/0073/ works, but I have found no way of relating this information to the X & Y position of the monitor:

Comment: Works fine for me on archlinux with openbox. Which specific platforms are you testing this on, and with which window-managers? Also, how exactly are you obtaining the `QScreen` object?

Comment: Windows 7, and Ubuntu 18.10 (Xorg?). QGuiApplication.screens and the signals QGuiApplication.screenAdded & QGuiApplication.screenRemoved.

Comment: Looking at the Qt source, it looks like the windows plugin doesn't even implement code for the serialNumber property

Comment: It looks like only x11 platforms are supported (via the xcb and eglfs plugins). The xcb plugin relies on xrandr to obtain the edid info. I have no idea why this wouldn't work on ubuntu - unless you somehow don't have the libxrandr package installed. The implementation of the qpa architecture is patchy and very poorly documented, so it's hard to diagnose the problem any further.

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jww I would disagree with your edit of my title, as I can't get the info I need from PyQt. so I'm looking for an alternative way, as indicated by my link to the win32com example

Comment: @Feel free to change it. You do say, *"We're using QScreen for the info we need, and this is great"*, so it is not clear what your problem is.