# obtain the manufacturer and product ID and serial number of the display using C++ under Linux

Tags: c++, linux, linux-device-driver

The goal is to obtain the manufacturer and product ID and the serial number of the display under the Linux platform. I eventually need to get this information in the program in C++.

The display could be a display connected via a video output connector or a built-in display. I hava tried to parse the edid file using `get-edid` and `parse-edid`. It works for some displays, but there is no product serial number.And the output of some other displays has some garbled characters.

How can I obtain these information programmatically? Is there some commands for reference?

Comment: Maybe related, [Get monitor serial number using PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55182931/608639).

Comment: EDID is indeed where the information originates. There are some caveats however. While most displays do have EDID, not all of them do. The EDID has two ways to encode the serial number (a 32-bit value and a 13-byte ASCII string), and they're *both* optional. The manufacturer and product IDs are mandatory. The most convenient way to get at this information depends on your environment and allowed/required dependencies. At the low level, it's perhaps possible to use libdrm to get at the EDID connector property.